# Constructor ill-formness and implicit deletion

Tags: c++, default-constructor

I'm trying to define some classes but I get some errors I'm not being able to decode.
I do not understand why it states I'm using `Test`'s constructor when I am not.

```
test.cpp: In constructor 'Test2::Test2(int)':
test.cpp:12:34: error: use of deleted function 'Test::Test()'
   explicit Test2(const int line) {}
                                  ^
test.cpp:3:7: note: 'Test::Test()' is implicitly deleted because the default definition would be ill-formed:
 class Test : public std::runtime_error {
       ^
test.cpp:3:7: error: no matching function for call to 'std::runtime_error::runtime_error()'
test.cpp:3:7: note: candidates are:
In file included from test.cpp:1:0:
C:/Development/MinGW/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/c++/stdexcept:119:5: note: std::runtime_error::runtime_error(const string&)
     runtime_error(const string& __arg);
     ^
C:/Development/MinGW/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/c++/stdexcept:119:5: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
C:/Development/MinGW/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/c++/stdexcept:112:9: note: std::runtime_error::runtime_error(const std::runtime_error&)
   class runtime_error : public exception
         ^
C:/Development/MinGW/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/c++/stdexcept:112:9: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
```

Minimal working example (gcc 4.9.1, `g++ -std=c++11`):

```
#include <stdexcept>

class Test : public std::runtime_error {
 public:
  virtual ~Test() noexcept {}

  virtual const char * what() const noexcept = 0;
};

class Test2 : public Test {
 public:
  explicit Test2(const int line) {}

  virtual const char * what() const noexcept { return ""; }
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your constructor in the class `Test2` does not pass any arguments to the base class. So the default constructor of the base class - which is `Test` - is used. And the same story with `Test` then - its default constructor tries to call the default constructor of its base class - `std::runtime_error` - which does not exist. Hence the error. You need to pass message string argument to `std::runtime_error`, e.g.:

```
Test() : std::runtime_error("some message") {}
```

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. But I don't want to call the base constructor, e.g. I may want to compute ```what``` online and do not use ```runtime_error```'s msg attribute whatsoever. If I wanted to call the base constructor I would have done so explicitly.

Comment: As far as I know C++98 also did not have the default constructor for `runtime_error`. Maybe your compiler provided it as an extension. If you want to have standard code you do not have a choice - `runtime_error` does not have default constructor, so you have to provide an argument.